# How to get the result of a asynchronous action in NGXS?

Tags: ngxs

I want to perform an action based to the result of an asynchronous NGXS action.

In a Angular frontend app I'm using NGXS for state management. Some of the actions involve talking to a backend via REST calls. Those actions are implemented as [asynchronous actions](https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/actions-life-cycle#asynchronous-actions), with the reducer functions in my [state classes](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/state) returning an Observable.

What I'm looking for is a way to get hands on the result of the backend call, to be able to perform some action.

One use case I'm trying to implement is navigation to just created objects: Business objects are created in the frontend (Angular) app with a couple of domain properties. They get persisted in the backend, and as a result an ID for this object is created and returned to the frontend, and incorporated into the NGXS store. As a direct response to this, I'd like to navigate to a detail view for the new object. To do so, I need

- (a) the information that the call has been returned successful, and
- (b) the answer from the backend (the ID in this case).

Another slightly more complicated use case is the assignment of a number of tags to an business object. The tags are entities by themselfes, and have an ID each. In the UI, the user can either pick existing or add new tags. Either way, multiple tags can be added in a single step in the UI, which means I have to

1. call the backend for each new tag to create the ID
2. after all missing tags are created, update the business object with the list of tag IDs

In general, there are use cases in the frontend that depend on the result of a backend call, and there is no clean way to find this result in the store (although it's in there)

I know I can subscribe to the Observable returned from the store's dispatch method (as shown in [asynchronous actions](https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/actions-life-cycle#asynchronous-actions)).
I also know about [action handlers](https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/action-handlers). In both cases I can attach code to the event of an action finished, but neither option enables me to get the result of the backend call. In the fist case, the Observable carries the whole store, while in the latter case I get the original Action, which is unfortunately missing the essential information (the ID).

Comment: Dude, you have to read docs attentively. The short answer is `The Observable that a dispatch returns has a void type, this is because there can be multiple states that listen to the same @Action, therefore it's not realistically possible to return the state from these actions since we don't know the form of them.`. Also why do you need a result of an action? You can create a service where you can return an observable and subscribe to

Comment: @overthesanity "You can create a service where you can return an observable and subscribe to" - I can't see how that will help me. Actually, I've implemented the backend communication in it's own service, with methods returning proper Observables. But as long as I use asyncronous actions to trigger calls to this service, I'm not able to get hold of those. And as for the dispatch method result, I've checked the result with ngxs 3.5.1 and it indeed holds the whole store, not void...

Comment: > `it indeed holds the whole store, not void` - You should not rely on this. It is not an explicit part of the interface and will be changing in v4. You should treat it as if it returns `void`.

Comment: > `But as long as I use asyncronous actions to trigger calls to this service` - why do you need actions to trigger calls to the service? what can't you do that directly?

Comment: >what can't you do that directly? Well, maybe thats the point. I took the whole asyncronous action thing from the docs (https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/actions-life-cycle#asynchronous-actions), and it made sense so far (wrap the whole user action into an ngxs action), but in this particular case it might make sense to do it the other way around. If I do the whole backend communication before kicking of an action, I have everything in place

Comment: @overthesanity I'll try that, thanks a lot!

Comment: I created this doc and I can tell you that action handler patches the state there. So basically you should not rely on the action result. You should rely on the state change.

Answer (score 1):

The part you're missing here are [selectors](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select). Dispatching actions is not supposed to give you back a result. The only purpose of the Observable returned by `store.dispatch()` is to tell you when the action's handlers are done.

To get to the data returned by your calls to the backend, you have to patch the state inside your action handler. And then, outside of your state, you can access the data using `store.select()` or `store.selectSnapshot()` depending on what you need. Your state class should look somewhat like this (untested):

```
@State()
export class SampleState {
  @Selector(SampleState)
  sampleSelector(state) {
    return state.sampleObject;
  }

  @Action(SampleAction)
  sampleAction(ctx: StateContext<any>, action: sampleAction) {
    return sampleBackendCall(/* ... */).pipe(
      tap((result) => {
        ctx.patchState({ sampleObject: result });
      }) 
    );
  }
}
```

Now you can access this result where ever you need using the `Store`. For the use case of navigating to an element after its creation, you can combine a subscription to `store.dispatch()` with a `store.selectSnapshot()` like this:

```
store.dispatch(new SampleAction()).subscribe(() => {
  navigateTo(store.selectSnapshot(SampleState.sampleSelector));
});
```

Note that in this easy case a `selectSnapshot` is perfectly fine, as we only want to get the value we just finished writing into the state. In most cases though, you will want to use `store.select()` or the `@Select()` decorator because they return Observables which enable you to also correctly display changes in your state.

That said, I'd like to add that if saving data inside the state is not necessary for you at all, then probably NGXS is the wrong library for you in the first place and you could as well just use an ordinary angular service directly returning the result of the backend call, like suggested in the comments.